# Tkinter Python , Trying to load a string from a dictionary which is loaded from file

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been coding this as a personal practice/test of Tkinter with python and I'm trying to load a file which contains a dictionary inside a dictionary and read that which shouldn't be the problem, however the problem is, that TempDict is not classed as defined.

I am also very sorry if some of the code is not indented properly it didn't copy and paste over very well so I had to make some corrections.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tm
import os
import pickle


class Quiz (tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self, *args , **kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args , **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Quiz")

        container = tk.Frame (self)
        container.pack (side = "top" , fill = "both" , expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure (0,weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure (0,weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Menu, Difficulty, QuestionsStart):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid (row = 0, column = 0 , sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Login")
        label.pack(pady = 10 , padx = 10)

        global Username
        User = tk.Label (self, text = "Username")
        User.pack()

        Username = tk.Entry(self)
        Username.pack()
        Pass = tk.Label (self, text = "Password")
        Pass.pack()

        Password = tk.Entry (self, show = "*")
        Password.pack()

        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Login",
                        command = lambda: Login(Username,Password,parent,controller,self) )
        button1.pack()

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = "Sign Up",
                        command = lambda: Signup())
        button2.pack()



class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Menu")
        label.pack()

        Label = tk.Label(self, text = "Please enter Maths or Chemsitry")
        Label.pack()

        Topic = tk.Entry(self)
        Topic.pack()

        Proceed = ttk.Button(self, text = "Proceed", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Difficulty))
        Proceed.pack()

        Result = ttk.Button(self, text = "Results",
                       command = lambda: Results(controller))
        Result.pack()

        Logout = ttk.Button(self, text = "Log Out",
                        command = lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        Logout.pack()



class Difficulty(tk.Frame):

    def __init__ (self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text = "Difficulty")
        label.pack()

        Label = tk.Label(self, text = "Please enter Easy, Medium or Hard")
        Label.pack()

        DifficultyInput = tk.Entry(self)
        DifficultyInput.pack()

        StartQuiz = tk.Button(self , text = "Start Quiz", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(QuestionsStart))
        StartQuiz.pack()



        backtomenu = ttk.Button(self, text = "Back to Menu",
                           command = lambda: controller.show_frame(Menu))
        backtomenu.pack()


def DictFromFile ():
    TempDict = {}
    try:
        with open("Questions.txt" , "r") as file:
            TempDict = eval(file.read())
            file.close()
    except IOError as error:
        print (error)
    print(TempDict)
    return TempDict

DictFromFile()

def QuizType(Topic, DifficultyInput):

    QuizSelection = str(Topic.get().lower() + DifficultyInput.get().lower())
    return QuizSelection

class QuestionsStart (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self , parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        Label = tk.Label(self, text = DictFromFile(TempDict[QuizSelection(Topic, DifficultyInput)]["Question1"]))
        Label.pack()




def Login(Username,Password,parent,controller,self):

    Usernames = []
    Login = True
    Username = Username.get()
    Password = Password.get()

    try:

        with open ("Usernames&Passwords.txt" , "rb" ) as file:
            for each in pickle.load(file):
                Usernames.append(each.strip("\n"))
            file.close()

    except IOError as error:
        print (error)

    for each in range(len(Usernames)):
        if Usernames[each] == Username :
            if Usernames[each + 1] == Password:
                Login = True
                controller.show_frame(Menu)
                break
            else:
                Login = False
        else:
           Login = False
    if Login == False:
        tm.showinfo("Your Username or Password is incorrect" , "Your Usename or Password is incorrect")

def Results (controller):

    UsersResults = []
    Counter = 0
    Topic = []
    Difficulty = []
    Mark = []
    Percentage = []
    Grade = []

    try:                      
        with open(Username.get() + ".txt" , "r" , encoding = "UTF-8") as file:
            for each in file:
                UsersResults.append(each.strip("\n"))

    except IOError as error:
        print(error)
    print (UsersResults)
    print (Counter)
    for each in range (len(UsersResults)):
        Topic = UsersResults[Counter]
        Difficulty = UsersResults[Counter + 1]
        Mark = UsersResults[Counter + 2]
        Percentage = UsersResults[Counter + 3]
        Grade = UsersResults[Counter + 4]
        Counter += 5



    return UsersResults






app = Quiz()
app.geometry ("500x300")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Notepad which contains the Dictionaries ][1]
[Error I have been getting][2]
[Username and Password][3]


  [1]: https://gyazo.com/8ea5faab3027411927762305535cb0c3
  [2]: https://gyazo.com/2d6a5d659020ee5aa259b61f5cbf3c08
  [3]: https://gyazo.com/1f7f87a17ce5749fa92e717fc6327035

Comment: Please include the shortest possible example data in your question. Nobody wants to click on links to download data just to test your code. Also, please reduce your code to a [mcve]. There is a whole lot of code which is completely unrelated to the question you're asking.

Comment: you have button `{}` to correctly format selected code. Put error message as text in question, not screenshot. Put `Questions.txt` as text in question, not screenshot. Now nobody can copy it to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `DictFromFile()` in wrong way in

```
tk.Label(self, text=DictFromFile(TempDict[QuizSelection(Topic, DifficultyInput)]["Question1"])
```

You can't run `DictFromFile()` with arguments.
It returns dictionary which you have to assing to variable and then you can get question.

It should be something like

```
temp_dict = DictFromFile()

question = temp_dict[QuizSelection(Topic, DifficultyInput)]["Question1"]

tk.Label(self, text=question)
```

Now you have dictionary `TempDict` in variable `temp_dict`.

But I see other problem - you use other variables which doesn't exists in this place - `QuizSelection`, `Topic`, `DifficultyInput`.
They exists as local variables in other functions and you can't use it like global variables.

You can get `QuizSelection` from function `QuizType()`

```
quiz_selection = QuizType(Topic, DifficultyInput)
question = temp_dict[quiz_selection]["Question1"]
```

but still you don't have access to variables `Topic`, `DifficultyInput`.

---

It looks like you don't know how to use functions.

You have to learn how to use `self.` in classes, too.